# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type class object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting android run time exception for this java class:
I am not getting where the problem is occurring, I have tried almost all similar questions' answers but no help! Also, I have tried to run the code by commenting almost all the unrelated functions, but that didn't rule out the error too.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private String intentsChild;
    private String curFirebaseLocation;
    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;
    private String mUsername;
    private String mPhotoUrl;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Button mSendButton;
    private RecyclerView mMessageRecyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private EditText mMessageEditText;
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage, MessageViewHolder>
            mFirebaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setStatusBarTranslucent(true);

        // Set default username is anonymous.
        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        //initialize facebook app activation
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getApplication());

        if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
            // Not signed in, launch the Sign In activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
            finish();
            return;
        } else {
            mUsername = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName();
            if (mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
                mPhotoUrl = mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            }
        }

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
                .build();

        // Initialize ProgressBar and RecyclerView.
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mMessageRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messageRecyclerView);
        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mMessageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        curFirebaseLocation = "users/" + mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().trim() + "/messages";
        intentsChild = "users/" + mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().trim() + "/intents";



        Toast.makeText(this, "users/" + mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//        if(mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(curFirebaseLocation).getParent() == null){
//            Toast.makeText(this, curFirebaseLocation + " already exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            IntentMessage tempintent = new IntentMessage("", "");
            FriendlyMessage tempmessage = new FriendlyMessage("Hello, I'm Ed, your personal assistant cum friend",
                    "Ed", "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/100/male3-512.png", "1476880306");
            mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(curFirebaseLocation).setValue(tempmessage);
            mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(intentsChild).setValue(tempintent);
//        }
        Toast.makeText(this, curFirebaseLocation, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        // New child entries
        mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage,
                MessageViewHolder>(
                FriendlyMessage.class,
                R.layout.item_message,
                MessageViewHolder.class,
                mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(curFirebaseLocation)) {


            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MessageViewHolder viewHolder,
                                              FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage, int position) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
                viewHolder.messageTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getText());
                viewHolder.messengerTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getName());
                if (friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl() == null) {
                    viewHolder.messengerImageView
                            .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat
                                    .getDrawable(MainActivity.this,
                                            tod));
                } else {
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                            .load(friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl())
                            .into(viewHolder.messengerImageView);
                }
                if (friendlyMessage.getName().equals("Ed")){
                    //TODO : Do this as it is necessary
//                    viewHolder.diffForRecSend.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.white));
//                    viewHolder.diffForRecSend.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.abcd123);
                }
                else {
                    //TODO : Do this as it is necessary
//                    viewHolder.diffForRecSend.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorAccent));
//                    viewHolder.diffForRecSend.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.abcd1234);
                }
            }
        };

        mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(intentsChild).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                IntentMessage newIntentMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(IntentMessage.class);
                String name = newIntentMessage.getIntentName();
                String fields = newIntentMessage.getIntentFields();
                if (name.equals("") || fields.equals(""))
                    return;
                IntentMessage temp = new IntentMessage("", "");
                mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(intentsChild).child("-KUWmGwxVe0HCYtYWfdI").setValue(temp);
//                IntentFiringActivity newIntentFiringActivity;
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildUpdated: " + name + fields);
                System.out.println("onChildUpdated: " + name + fields);
                if (name.equals("gmail"))
                    fireGmailIntent(fields.split("\\$"));
                else if (name.equals("alarm1"))
                    fireAlarmIntent(fields.split("\\$"));
                else if (name.equals("alarm2"))
                    fireAlarmIntent2(fields.split("\\$"));
//                newIntentFiringActivity = new IntentFiringActivity(name, fields);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                IntentMessage newIntentMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(IntentMessage.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildRemoved: " + newIntentMessage.getIntentName() + newIntentMessage.getIntentFields());
                System.out.println("onChildRemoved: " + newIntentMessage.getIntentName() + newIntentMessage.getIntentFields());
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });


        mFirebaseAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
                int friendlyMessageCount = mFirebaseAdapter.getItemCount();
                int lastVisiblePosition =
                        mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                // If the recycler view is initially being loaded or the
                // user is at the bottom of the list, scroll to the bottom
                // of the list to show the newly added message.
                if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                        (positionStart >= (friendlyMessageCount - 1) &&
                                lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                    mMessageRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
                }
            }
        });

        mMessageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        mMessageRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
        mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);

        mMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });

        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Long tsLong = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
                String ts = tsLong.toString();
                FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new
                        FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(),
                        mUsername,
                        mPhotoUrl,
                        ts);
                mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(curFirebaseLocation)
                        .push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                mMessageEditText.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    private void fireAlarmIntent(String[] intentFields) {
        int hours = Integer.parseInt(intentFields[0].trim());
        int minutes;
        if(intentFields[1].trim().equals("")){
            minutes = 0;
        }
        else {
            minutes = Integer.parseInt(intentFields[1].trim());
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hours);
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minutes);
        int temp1 = 1;
        startActivityForResult(i, temp1);
        String temp = "Alarm set for " + hours + " : " + minutes;
        Log.d(TAG, temp);
//        Toast.makeText(this, temp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void fireAlarmIntent2(String[] intentFields) {
        int hours = Integer.parseInt(intentFields[0].trim());
        int curhours = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int finalhours =  (hours + curhours) % 24;
        int curmin = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, finalhours);
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, curmin);
        int temp1 = 1;
        startActivityForResult(i, temp1);
        String temp = "Alarm set for " + finalhours + " : " + curmin;
        Log.d(TAG, temp);
        Log.d(TAG, "currentHours: " + curhours + " and received from server : " + hours + " hence total is : " + finalhours);
//        Toast.makeText(this, temp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private void fireGmailIntent(String[] intentFields) {
        String[] email = new String[1];
        email[0] = intentFields[0];
        Log.d(TAG, "My unique log " + email[0]);
        String subject = intentFields[1];
        String body = intentFields[2];
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, email);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        Log.d(TAG, "My unique log " + email[0] + "__" + subject + "__" + body);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            int temp = 4;
            startActivityForResult(intent, temp);
            Log.d(TAG, "My unique log " + email[0] + "__" + subject + "__" + body + "again");
        }
    }

    protected void setStatusBarTranslucent(boolean makeTranslucent) {
        if (makeTranslucent) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        } else {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }
    }
    // Firebase instance variables

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in.
        // TODO: Add code to check if user is signed in.
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.sign_out_menu:
                mFirebaseAuth.signOut();
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
                mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
                startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView messageTextView;
        public TextView messengerTextView;
        public CircleImageView messengerImageView;
        public LinearLayout diffForRecSend;

        public MessageViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            messageTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
            messengerTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messengerTextView);
            messengerImageView = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messengerImageView);
            diffForRecSend = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_main_id);
        }
    }

}
```

This is the logcat error:

```
Process: com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat, PID: 20107
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat.FriendlyMessage
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzd(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:147)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:136)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:176)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5453)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5486)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4723)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4599)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1988)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1384)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1347)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:549)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3003)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2881)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3265)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16969)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5583)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1189)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16969)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5583)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16969)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5583)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16969)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5583)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16969)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5583)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2001)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1844)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1753)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16969)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5583)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2728)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16969)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5583)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2552)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2255)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1321)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6708)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:894)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:696)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:880)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:822)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Loop
```

The following is just a snapshot of my json structure for reference:

```
{
    "users" : {
        "ERyWg81WxrXUb0sjsu9hv9T7K0E3" : {
            "intents" : {
                "intentName" : "",
                "intentValue" : ""
              },
              "messages" : {
                "-KViVgc7ZG051eMXP0-5" : {
                  "name" : "Ed",
                  "text" : "Hello, I'm Ed, your personal assistant cum friend",
                  "timestamp" : "1476880306"
                }
              }         
        },
        "Y9UNlizDSobddO8cdq7K4ChipYa2" : {
            "intents" : {
                "intentName" : "",
                "intentValue" : ""
              },
              "messages" : {
                "-KViVgc7ZG051eMXP0-5" : {
                  "name" : "Ed",
                  "text" : "Hello, I'm Ed, your personal assistant cum friend",
                  "timestamp" : "1476880306"
                }
              } 
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
OK, after debugging, I have discovered that the problem lies in these lines :
So, the problem is now narrowed down. Please help me find the rest of the error:

```
mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage,
        MessageViewHolder>(
        FriendlyMessage.class,
        R.layout.item_message,
        MessageViewHolder.class,
        mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(curFirebaseLocation)) {


    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(MessageViewHolder viewHolder,
                                      FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage, int position) {
//...//
}
```

**EDIT 2**:
I noted an important aspect: While running the app without a data connection, the app still was showing the error "unfortunately Ed has stopped", this is not natural as earlier when my app was working(when my app was at one stage less than what it is today), it first used to load some data from the firebase database, then showed error. But this time, it shows the error even before it loads the data from the database, this leads to a conclusion that the error doesn't lie in the `snapshot` part of the problem, as if it would have had the case, the app wouldn't have shown the error in the offline state as until the data loads up, it should have been showing the progress dialog continuously.
**EDIT 3** I found why am I getting the error:
This line :
        mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(
                FriendlyMessage.class,
                R.layout.item_message,
                MessageViewHolder.class,
                mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(curFirebaseLocation)) {...
In this line, when I pass some other string instead of `curFirebaseLocation`, there is no error and my app loads up fine but when I pass the `curFirebaseLocation` variable, I get the error as seen in the LogCat above. Now, I only need to know why am I getting the error `unable to convert java.lang.String to ...FriendlyMessage`, even when the value of both `curFirebaseLocation` and the string that I pass(upon which I get no error) is exactly the same. I think it has soething to do with the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. Please help!!
**NOTE:** I logged the output of the `curFirebaseLocation` and `intentsMessage` Strings and found out that they were perfectly fine. When I copied them and pasted them in the browser, they led me to the exactly expected location.
Please mention if any more clarification is needed.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the authentication and database synchronisation of Firebase, the user which was accessing the database was not registered in the auth section, also there were a few minor glitches, the code is working fine now and I'm getting the child nodes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`Firebase` needs an empty constructor in class. Make sure you explicitly defined an empty constructor in your `FriendlyMessage` class.

Comment: their is an empty constructor in `IntentMessage` class. And, the error is related to Friendlyessage class.

Comment: See your `dataSnapshot`. I think it contains the snapshot of complete data. If this is true, then you have complete data in response which you cannot cast to `FriendlyMessage`.

Comment: Sir the `dataSnapshot` your are talking about is related to the `IntentsMessage` class, this part is completely of secondary use, when I commented this entire function and ran the code, I got the same error. Also , when I commented most of the parts of the code except the ones which I have mentioned in the EDIT above, the error didn't go, so I suspect the error lies in the above few lines only.

Comment: I do have an empty constructor in the`FriendlyMessage` class too

Comment: It should also be noted that earlier my code was working fine, but since the time I changed my database structure and the link to the firebase database location in the android code, the error is coming.